# How can you allow scrolling in a div with in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been trying to add scrolling to my div which is in a div. I have tried to add via CSS though that has not worked. When a user gets on the site they can scroll down or up to an icon and then click on it to open it to get information. For example if a user clicks the about us icon it would have a paragraph of info in which they can scroll up and down the text. I cant figure out how to create that scroll bar.Instead the text is automatically cut off/adjusted. Ive tried to use `style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;"` though that has not worked.

**What is happening:** https://gyazo.com/8d89a1e560393f8352a42b5912171fed

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});


document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
    translateX: {
      value: 200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
    translateX: {
      value: -200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    //this is down
    //this will open it up
    slot.prev();

  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    slot.next();
  }
}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
    translateX: {
      value: 200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
    translateX: {
      value: -200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  if (delta < 0) {
    //This is for the scrolling down
    // animation opens up the brakets

    slot.prev();

  }
  if (delta > 0) {
    slot.next();
  }
});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).index() == '1') {
    console.log("the fucks");

    $('#aboutID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      var div = $("<p id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>").hide();
      $(this).replaceWith(div);
      $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
    });



  }
  if ($(this).index() == '2') {
    console.log("jobs page");
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Underscores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>


</head>

<body>


  <div id="left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id="theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt="" class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="right"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps (run the snippet in full page mode):

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});


document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
    translateX: {
      value: 200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
    translateX: {
      value: -200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    //this is down
    //this will open it up
    slot.prev();

  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    slot.next();
  }
}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
    translateX: {
      value: 200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
    translateX: {
      value: -200,
      duration: 500
    }
  });
  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  if (delta < 0) {
    //This is for the scrolling down
    // animation opens up the brakets

    slot.prev();

  }
  if (delta > 0) {
    slot.next();
  }
});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).index() == '1') {

    $('#aboutID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      var div = $("<p id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>").hide();
      $(this).replaceWith(div);
      $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
    });



  }
  if ($(this).index() == '2') {
    console.log("jobs page");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#middle {
  width: 280px;
  float: left;
}

#foo {
  height: 270px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Underscores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id="theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt="" class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="right"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow-y:Scroll; to the  which contains data to be scrolled.Remember do not use min-Height for your inner ,Instead use height. :)